# Issue with saving Word Doc as PDF "This is not a valid file name"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to save a Word Document as a PDF, but I'm getting an error box

> "Run-time error '-214747259 (80004005)
>   This is not a valid filename."

This is the code I have for it:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim equipName As String, equipError As String, fileDate As String, pdfName As String, filePath As String

filePath = "C:\"
equipName = Replace(Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, _
    Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text) - 1), "/", "-")
equipError = Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text, Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text) - 1)
fileDate = Replace(Date, "/", "")
pdfName = equipName & "_" & equipError & "_" & fileDate

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=filePath & pdfName & ".pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

End Sub
```

The code to save the file as a PDF is what I took from a Macro recorded of me SaveAs-ing. The actual file path is much longer, but for simplicity's sake, I have it as "C:\" (which doesn't work either).

Comment: Please show us the resulting value of the variable `pdfName` else we're just going to be taking random guesses...

Comment: Right now I just have random letters/numbers in the cells for equipName and equipError; they are:

equipName = FTIR and equipError = 1234abc

so pdfNamem (as it shows whith mouse over) = "FTIR_1234abc_08302012"

Comment: there seem to be some extra parameters to the command, based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238907%28v=office.12%29.aspx). This is what I get when I record the save of a file: `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= "C:\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= False`

Comment: That looks like it's Excel, not Word. Maybe the parameters are different for the two? I recorded a Macro in Word for the save part, did you in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the issue, mostly. I don't know why/where it is doing this, but it is adding a 'next-line' character (Chr(13)). So, right before telling it to save the file, I inserted the line:

```
pdfName = Replace(pdfName, Chr(13),"")
```

Now it is saving with no problem. My co-worker was helping me with this issue, and he found that if you took:

```
pdfNameLen = Len(pdfName)
```

it returns the length as 2 more than if you counted the visible characters (because of the 2 cell entries). He used:

```
Left(*cell text*, Len(*cell text*) - 2)
```

for where it collects both cell values, where the only difference is at the very end (-2 instead of -1, to get rid of the cell formatting and Char(13)). At the exact same time we said "got it!".

Thanks, all, for helping! Final code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

Dim equipName As String, equipError As String, fileDate As String, pdfName As String, filePath As String, pdfLen As Integer

filePath = "C:\"
equipName = Replace(Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, _
    Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text) - 1), "/", "-")
equipError = Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text, Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text) - 1)
fileDate = Replace(Date, "/", "")
pdfName = equipName & "_" & equipError & "_" & fileDate

pdfName = Replace(pdfName, Chr(13), "")

ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=filePath & pdfName, _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
    BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The text you have in the ActiveDocument in Cell1,2 and 2,2 may have special characters. If you don't see any windows reserved characters like \ / : * ? " < > | then you may have a strange hidden or white character.

Also if DATE has : in it, then it won't save. You'll have to strip all of the reserved chars because a windows filename cannot contain any of the following characters:
\ / : * ? " < > |

Comment: There are no Windows Reserved chars in any of the strigs (not visible when I hold mouse over variable in step-by-step running). How can I get rid of the hidden/white characters?

Comment: Try to do a compare between a hardcoded value for equipname="yourcellvalue1" and equiperror="yourcellvalue2" and then see if they equal what you are getting back from ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2) and ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2). If they don't equal/match, then  probably try more cleanup, like replacing carriage return, space, and null chars as well as / like you have already.

Comment: What does Pdffilename variable say it is? Is that a valid file path/name?

Comment: The path isn't the problem; using filePath works as long as I manually type in a file name instead of using the compiled one. As for pdfName, I answered it above, saw that question first.

Answer (score 3):

this will strip out unwanted chars:

```
Function CleanFilename(CurrentFilename As String) As String
Dim MyArray()
Dim x As Integer

    MyArray = Array("<", ">", "|", "/", "*", "\", "?", """", ":")
    For x = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        CurrentFilename = Replace(CurrentFilename, MyArray(x), "_", 1)
    Next x
    CleanFilename = CurrentFilename
End Function
```

I wouldn't recommend running it on the fully qualified pathname, but on the `pdfName`, else `C:\test.pdf` would become `C__test.pdf`

Comment: I ran this function, but it's still returning the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though, I never would have thought of this!